# If $a,b,c$ are positive and integers, $a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c}}=\frac{25}{19}$, then $a+b+c=?$

Tags: calculus, puzzle

I've found this question and tried to solve it, but failed

If a,b,c are positive and integers, $a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c}}=\frac{25}{19}$, then $a+b+c=?$
and how to get it?

Comment: Can you show how you attempted to solve the problem. Also here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying functions.

Comment: You should show how you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here, I got the answer from someone, and the values for a,b,c by trying but failed to get a mathical way to find it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$a < a+\frac{1}{b+\frac1c} <a+1$$

Then do the same with
$$b < b+\frac1c \leq b+1$$

Comment: I haven't got it by this hint yet :(

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{25}{19} &=& 1+\frac{6}{19} \\[5pt]
               &=& 1+\frac{1}{\frac{19}{6}} \\[5pt]
               &=& 1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{6}} \\
 \end{eqnarray*}$

$\therefore a+b+c=1+3+6=10$

P.S. The above work shows the existence of $a,b,c$.  For the uniqueness see also Ex. 1 on p.3 of http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/contfrac.pdf

Comment: But what if there are other solutions ;)

Comment: No, because any real numbers have unique expression of regular continued fractions.  In case of rational, it terminates; otherwise indefinite. E.g. $\sqrt{2}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}$

Comment: Rational numbers have two continued fractions ;) Now if one knows continuous fractions, it is easy to argue that the second representation cannot lead to a solution....

Comment: Be careful, I said "regular" which means $a\in \mathbf {Z}$ and $b, c, \ldots \in \mathbf {N}$. Mathematically, for non-zero $x=a+\frac{1}{b+\ldots}, a=\lfloor x \rfloor, b=\lfloor \frac{1}{x-a} \rfloor, \ldots$ All the "convergents" can be uniquely determined by simple calculator.   See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: Are you saying that $$\frac{25}{19} =1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{1}}}$$ is not true?

Comment: Again be careful, I used $\lfloor . \rfloor$.  In this case $c=\lfloor \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}} \rfloor = 6 \neq 5$.  It terminates at 6 **not** 1 !!

Comment: I am careful, the formula uniquely determines the CFR for irrational numbers, but it doesn't give us all the CFR for rational numbers The fraction I posted IS a continuous fraction representation for $25/19$, it does satisfy your definition of regular . Just read the second paragraph of the website you suggested.

Comment: Also, can you please show me how you can use the same method to solve $$a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+\frac{1}{d}}}=\frac{25}{19}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34494/discussion-between-ng-chung-tak-and-n-s).