# Find $p+q+r+s$ if $p+\frac{1}{q+\frac{1}{r+\frac{1}{s}}}=\frac{89}{68}$, $p,q,r,s$ are natural numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The main question is :

Suppose $p,q,r,s$ are natural numbers. Find $p+q+r+s$ if
$$p+\frac{1}{q+\frac{1}{r+\frac{1}{s}}}=\frac{89}{68}$$

You may think that this problem is easy, that $p,q,r,s$ can be substituted for a single variable $x$, and after finding a quartic in $x$, we can see the coefficents of $x^4$ and $x^3$ and find the sum of roots. But, the $x^3$ term magically disappears, and we get the sum of roots to be 0, which is not possible.
This was what I tried. Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: May refer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617171/if-a-b-c-are-positive-and-integers-a-frac1b-frac1c-frac2519/1617177#1617177)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would try - given that what you see on the left is a [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) - is to expand $89/68$ as a continued fraction. It may or may not work, so I'll try it now:

$$\frac{89}{68}=1+\frac{21}{68}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{\frac{68}{21}}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{5}{21}}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{\frac{21}{5}}}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{5}}}$$

And there you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{89}{68} = 1+\frac{1}{\frac{68}{21}} = 1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{5}{21}} = 1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{5}}}$$